# How really does the layout of malloc_chunk look like?

Tags: c, malloc

(Updated some of my explanation at the bottom)

I'm studying how malloc works,
after having a basic understanding of the structure of chunk, I decided to write a small program to have a closer look of what's really going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
An allocated chunk looks like this:
    chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of previous chunk, if unallocated (P clear)  |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of chunk, in bytes                     |A|M|P|
      mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             User data starts here...                          .
            .                                                               .
            .             (malloc_usable_size() bytes)                      .
            .                                                               |
nextchunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             (size of chunk, but used for application data)    |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of next chunk, in bytes                |A|0|1|
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
*/
int main()
{
    void *a = malloc(24);
    void *b = malloc(16);
    void *chunk_b = NULL, *chunk_after_b = NULL, *chunk_a = NULL;
    
    chunk_a = a - 0x8; //8 byte before a (user data)
    chunk_b = a + malloc_usable_size(a);
    chunk_after_b = b + malloc_usable_size(b);

    *(int *)a = 0xa; 
    *(int *)b = 0xb;

    printf("a:0x%x malloc_usable_size:%d(0x%x)\n", a, malloc_usable_size(a), malloc_usable_size(a));
    printf("b:0x%x malloc_usable_size:%d(0x%x)\n\n", b, malloc_usable_size(b), malloc_usable_size(b));
    
    printf("chunk_a[0]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", chunk_a, ((int *)chunk_a)[0]);
    printf("chunk_a[1]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", &((int *)chunk_a)[1], ((int *)chunk_a)[1]);
    printf("chunk_a[2]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n\n", &((int *)chunk_a)[2], ((int *)chunk_a)[2]);
    
    printf("chunk_b[0]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", chunk_b, ((int *)chunk_b)[0]);
    printf("chunk_b[1]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", &((int *)chunk_b)[1], ((int *)chunk_b)[1]);
    printf("chunk_b[2]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n\n", &((int *)chunk_b)[2], ((int *)chunk_b)[2]);
    
    printf("chunk_after_b[0]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", chunk_after_b, ((int *)chunk_after_b)[0]);
    printf("chunk_after_b[1]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n", &((int *)chunk_after_b)[1], ((int *)chunk_after_b)[1]);
    printf("chunk_after_b[2]:0x%x value:0x%04x \n\n", &((int *)chunk_after_b)[2], ((int *)chunk_after_b)[2]);

    free(a);
    free(b); 
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I got:

```
a:0x625ca2a0 malloc_usable_size:24(0x18)
b:0x625ca2c0 malloc_usable_size:24(0x18)

chunk_a[0]:0x625ca298 value:0x0021
chunk_a[1]:0x625ca29c value:0x0000 
chunk_a[2]:0x625ca2a0 value:0x000a  -->mem (user data)
 
chunk_b[0]:0x625ca2b8 value:0x0021 
chunk_b[1]:0x625ca2bc value:0x0000 
chunk_b[2]:0x625ca2c0 value:0x000b -->mem (user data)
 
chunk_after_b[0]:0x625ca2d8 value:0x0411 
chunk_after_b[1]:0x625ca2dc value:0x0000 
chunk_after_b[2]:0x625ca2e0 value:0x6e756863

(gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) Target: x86_64-linux-gnu)
```

As my understanding, malloc() will return the address of "User data" section, so minus it with 8 indicating 8 byte of "Size of chunk" and "Size of previous chunk" should be the start of such chunk (chunk_a in the example), for another thing, plus with malloc_usable_size() should be the start of nextchunk (chunk_b in the example).

The result turns out something doesn't make sense to me.

Where I think the "Size of chunk" should be, are chunk_a[1] and chunk_b[1], but both of theirs value are just 0. However, where I think the "Size of previous chunk" should be, chunk_a[0] and chunk_b[0], actually got value 0x21 which is 33 in decimal, and can get 32 after minus it with 1 for the LSB P.

This number do looks like something to me, as malloc_usable_size(a) is 24 in decimal for the size of user data, after adding it with 8, which also indicating 8 byte of "Size of chunk" and "Size of previous chunk", will also get 32 for the actual size of chunk.

So where really should the "Size of chunk" section be, did I misunderstand something?

---

Thanks for all the suggestions in comment, I had done some more test and it seems reasonable for me now.

The key is that I had treat both `Size of previous chunk` and `Size of chunk` as 4 byte each wrongly, which both of them should be 8 byte since I am compiling for x86_64 system.

Following this approach I rewrote the experiment program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    
    int i=0;
    void *a = malloc(24);
    void *b = malloc(16);
    void *chunk_b = NULL, *chunk_a = NULL;
    
    chunk_a = (u_int64_t *)a - 2;
    chunk_b = a + malloc_usable_size(a);

    ((u_int8_t *)a)[0] = 0xa0;
    ((u_int8_t *)a)[23] = 0xa1;
    ((u_int8_t *)b)[0] = 0xb0;

    printf("a:0x%x malloc_usable_size:%d(0x%x)\n", a, malloc_usable_size(a), malloc_usable_size(a));
    printf("b:0x%x malloc_usable_size:%d(0x%x)\n\n", b, malloc_usable_size(b), malloc_usable_size(b));

    
    printf("chunk_a[0]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n", chunk_a, ((u_int64_t *)chunk_a)[0]);
    printf("chunk_a[1]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n", &((u_int64_t *)chunk_a)[1], ((u_int64_t *)chunk_a)[1]);
    printf("chunk_a[2]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n", &((u_int64_t *)chunk_a)[2], ((u_int64_t *)chunk_a)[2]);
    for(i = 0; i<24;i++)
    {
         printf("a[%d]:0x%x value:0x%02x \n", i, &((u_int8_t *)a)[i], ((u_int8_t *)a)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("chunk_b[0]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n", chunk_b, ((u_int64_t *)chunk_b)[0]);
    printf("chunk_b[1]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n", &((u_int64_t *)chunk_b)[1], ((u_int64_t *)chunk_b)[1]);
    printf("chunk_b[2]:0x%x value:0x%016x \n\n", &((u_int64_t *)chunk_b)[2], ((u_int64_t *)chunk_b)[2]);

   free(b);
   free(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the result this time:

```
a:0xc2a4b2a0 malloc_usable_size:24(0x18)
b:0xc2a4b2c0 malloc_usable_size:24(0x18)

chunk_a[0]:0xc2a4b290 value:0x0000000000000000
chunk_a[1]:0xc2a4b298 value:0x0000000000000021
chunk_a[2]:0xc2a4b2a0 value:0x00000000000000a0
a[0]:0xc2a4b2a0 value:0xa0
a[1]:0xc2a4b2a1 value:0x00
a[2]:0xc2a4b2a2 value:0x00
a[3]:0xc2a4b2a3 value:0x00
a[4]:0xc2a4b2a4 value:0x00
a[5]:0xc2a4b2a5 value:0x00
a[6]:0xc2a4b2a6 value:0x00
a[7]:0xc2a4b2a7 value:0x00
a[8]:0xc2a4b2a8 value:0x00
a[9]:0xc2a4b2a9 value:0x00
a[10]:0xc2a4b2aa value:0x00
a[11]:0xc2a4b2ab value:0x00
a[12]:0xc2a4b2ac value:0x00
a[13]:0xc2a4b2ad value:0x00
a[14]:0xc2a4b2ae value:0x00
a[15]:0xc2a4b2af value:0x00
a[16]:0xc2a4b2b0 value:0x00
a[17]:0xc2a4b2b1 value:0x00
a[18]:0xc2a4b2b2 value:0x00
a[19]:0xc2a4b2b3 value:0x00
a[20]:0xc2a4b2b4 value:0x00
a[21]:0xc2a4b2b5 value:0x00
a[22]:0xc2a4b2b6 value:0x00
a[23]:0xc2a4b2b7 value:0xa1

chunk_b[0]:0xc2a4b2b8 value:0x0000000000000021
chunk_b[1]:0xc2a4b2c0 value:0x00000000000000b0
chunk_b[2]:0xc2a4b2c8 value:0x0000000000000000
```

At first, I had think both `Size of previous chunk` and `Size of chunk` should be 4 bytes because the size returned by malloc_usable_size() won't matched the position of `nextchunk` if I add the returned value (0x18 for this example) from start of `user data` (0xa77ef2a0 for this example).

What I had misunderstand is that `Size of previous chunk` **WILL** be also count as the data field for previous chunk if the LSB P of `Size of chunk` was setted up indicating the previous chunk is in used.

So for the experiment I had set the last byte of allocated memory (0xc2a4b2b7 ) as "0xa1", following should be the `Size of chunk` of chunk_b (0xc2a4b2b8), AND IT DOES!

Now this totally reasonable for me, but if I'm still misunderstand something pleas let me know, and thanks for all the comments again.

Comment: There is no one single implementation of `malloc`; there are various implementations. Why do you think the implementation you are using has the data layout you show? Where did you get the information about that data layout? Which implementation of `malloc` are you using?

Comment: @EricPostpischil 
I got this layout chart at [glibc/malloc/malloc.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#malloc_chunk), and sorry for a dumb question, how to check which actual implementation do the compiler linked to?

Comment: Just at a glance, the size fields are of type `INTERNAL_SIZE_T`, and that is likely defined to be `size_t`, and you are compiling for x86_64. So that would make the fields eight bytes long. Why do you think they are four bytes? What happens when you treat them as eight bytes?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I do think they are 4 bytes because it wouldn't make sense if `malloc_usable_size(a)` return 24 for them being 8 bytes each.

But I do have also done an experiment if they are 8 bytes (minus 16 from a), and I don't think this is the case:
`chunk_a[0]:0xec8ba290 value:0x0000`  `chunk_a[1]:0xec8ba294 value:0x0000`  `chunk_a[2]:0xec8ba298 value:0x0021`  ` chunk_a[3]:0xec8ba29c value:0x0000` 
`chunk_a[4]:0xec8ba2a0 value:0x000a`

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry for the such certain answer priviously, after more experiment I think I had found out where the problem is, and **YES I should treat them as 8 bytes**,  `malloc_usable_size(a)` should had also count the size of `Size of previous chunk` for `nextchunk` since the P bit in `nextchunk` is set to 1.